# Why do we use GLSL(Shader) instead of CUDA?

Tags: glsl, gpu, cuda

I'm meaning GLSL and CUDA both utilize GPU to their maximum power and in some cases, I heard CUDA runs faster on Nvidia graphic card. So my question is why don't we use CUDA more often for GPU graphic calculation. I know it's not cross-platform since it's exclusive to Nvidia GPU, plus it doesn't have basic 3d math. But Nvidia is kinda Dominant in the gaming community and 3d math it's not that hard to write. (I wrote 3d rendering engine on CPU from scratch). Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Shaders are specialized for well, graphic output.

Answer (score 2):

The intuition that CUDA is objectively "better than" dedicated rendering APIs for common rendering workloads is not a good guide.

These are not two competing software libraries that serve the same use case, where you have to choose one or the other. They're two different ways of talking to the GPU hardware, and you can use both in a single application if you have some operations to perform that are more convenient with CUDA and others that are more convenient with OpenGL.

[Here's an NVidia presentation showing CUDA and OpenGL interop](https://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC/documents/1055_GTC09.pdf), as one example.

Something you may notice is it takes a bit more code to render a textured quad via CUDA than it does in a vanilla OpenGL app, even though the work the GPU does in the end is the same (and you'd likely find no significant performance difference for well-written code on well-tuned drivers). That's because a rendering API like OpenGL assumes you're going to want to be doing things like rendering textured quads, so it works in abstractions and defaults that make that use case more convenient.

But you'd have to work harder to make the OpenGL pipeline, which expects to be talking about vertices and pixel colours, do general-purpose computing like computing culling volumes. That's why GPGPU tech like CUDA, OpenCL, DirectCompute, and compute shaders in Vulkan and other APIs exist, to step outside the abstractions that are so convenient for basic rendering when what we want to do is *not* basic rendering.

So the real question is: "Is the job I want to do well-served by the rendering pipeline?" If so, use a rendering API for that job. If you have a different job that's not well-served by that pipeline, consider using a general purpose compute API for that job. And when you have a job that needs both, you chop it up into steps that work well with compute shaders or steps that work well with rendering shaders, and tackle each in turn.

Note though that CUDA isn't doing anything fundamentally different than cross-platform compute shader options, so you don't have to lock yourself into NVidia cards to gain the benefits of GPGPU computing - unless you just happen to prefer the style of working in that API.